# How to contain HTML in a table on a WP site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm looking to add a table on my wordpress site that contains a body of text in the left column and a contact form in the right column (made with WPForms). I'm using TablePress to create the table and it is achieving what I am aiming for however I'm looking to expand the width of the table and make it responsive.

I'm using CSS within Table Press' plugin options to try and expand the table width:

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-1 .column-2 {
width: ___px;
}
```

And while I understand that the CSS isn't responsive, the table width isn't changing by a great deal at all.

Should I be approaching this a different way?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You can use percentages instead of pixels. When the columns are both 50%, they will expand (or contract) to use the available space.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've just changed the code to read "width: 50%;", they have become responsive. However I still find that the contact form is still too thin, as if the column width isn't wide enough for that side of the table. Could you advise how I can get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment above, you can use percentages instead of pixels:

```
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-1 .column-2 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

You might be able to tweak this and get away with it, by making adding a responsive rule:

```
/* Default rule - columns are 50% of the screen */
.tablepress-id-1 .column-1,
.tablepress-id-1 .column-2 {
    width: 50%;
}

/* Responsive rule - tweak the widths until you find a solution... */
/* Specifically, on screens up to 600px, make the right column 60% */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .tablepress-id-1 .column-1 {
        width: 40%;
    }
    .tablepress-id-1 .column-2 {
        width: 60%;
    }
}
```

The problem is that tables are just not mobile responsive. On a mobile device, you need those columns to stack, so the text would appear above the form in a single column.

To give you a very simple example, the HTML would be:

```
<div class="leftcol">
  text goes here
</div>
<div class="rightcol">
  form goes here
</div>
```

And the CSS would be:

```
.leftcol {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
.rightcol {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .leftcol,
    .rightcol {
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked perfectly for me. It still isn't stretching the width of the full page though - I have tried spacing it out with padding in the css and it just results in the WP Form stacking underneath the text rather than being beside it even though there's plenty of room on the page?

Comment: The thing to remember is the width property include the content, padding and border, but does not include the margin. So if there is a margin on any of the elements, that could force things wider than 100%, which would mean they stack. I've modified my answer to add `margin:0`. However, some people like to make the element widths 49.5% to allow for a 1% overlap. Try playing with the widths and see if that helps.

Comment: My code is as follows                                                                         
    .leftcol {
    padding-top:30px;
    width:70%;
    float:left;
}
.rightcol {
    width:70%;
    float:right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 140px) {
    .leftcol,
    .rightcol {
    width: 140%;
    float:left;
    }
}
And it is resulting in [this](https://imgur.com/a/eJjT2GO) - I'm hoping I'm making a bit more sense with the attached link. Thank you for your help thus far, I really appreciate your patience!

Comment: If you think of your available width as 100%, the problem is both the leftcol and rightcol are 70%, making 140% (which is too wide to fit inside of 100%, so the columns stack). Change leftcol to `width:30%` and then should fit next to one another on the page. In the `@media` code, set them both to 100%. Check out https://jsfiddle.net/L2480xf6/1/ - drag the screen smaller to see them stack when less than 600px.

Comment: Yep, that makes sense. I initially had them at 50% each and they sat side by side, I the ratio split (eg 60%, 40% etc) as I wanted my text column to be wider - yet that meant my forms would be thinner so I tried increasing the (max-width:) to 140px to expanding the both of them to fit the full width of the page (which as you could see didn't work). I really just want the form to fill the white space in this image [here](https://imgur.com/a/o9KYf3A) but no matter how much I push and pull the custom css it seems like it's just not stretching beyond that space...

Comment: Ok, I think I get it - you want to use that blank space to the right of the two columns? Unfortunately, that's going to be reliant on the theme you're using. The "100%" we've been talking about is 100% of the space in the parent or container class. You would have to modify the theme (or select a "Full Width" page template) in order to use that space.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was hoping for! I changed to a Full Width page template and it worked exactly as I was hoping. I had a feeling there could have been some imaginary bound. Except my only issue now is that it is not stacking in mobile view, [like this](https://imgur.com/a/yyJpViF) - have you got any ideas?

Comment: Yep :) This code `@media only screen and (max-width: 100px) {`. The 100px is the "break point" - the point at which the mobile styling is applied and the elements become 100% and stack. That's why in my code I've set `max-width: 600px` - that means, for screens 600px wide or smaller, the elements will stack. For larger screens (like laptops and desktops), the elements will sit next to one another.

Comment: Oh yep! I forgot to update my max-width -_-'! Thank you so much for all of your help, you're a legend!!